# SP2010 Claims Access Denied

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth

Something happened in the course of two days where all claims users are getting access denied.

This is what my claims id looks like when looking at policy for web application (it has full control and will always get access denied):
[image: policyforwebapp]

But when I log in with NTLM, and put the all authenticated users group to have access, this is what my claims id looks like (after logging in with claims):

[image]

Perhaps this isn't a problem but I was expecting the same prefix. Ideally,I would like to read on where the prefix comes from as well. the 't' stands for Trusted STS, c stands for other claims, 5 is for email address, but where does that 'g' come from? Is it possible that my people picker is selecting the wrong person?

I used to have object cache errors, so those have been resolved: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrasg/setting-the-super-user-account-on-sharepoint-2010-and-getting-access-denied-errors-afterwards)

What I'm left with is possibly following this article for troubleshooting since it sounds like there is a problem with the claims that are being created. http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/02/13/figuring-out-what-claims-you-have-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Is there anything else that I can read to help troubleshoot this? Thanks

Comment: found out the g is custom claims provider, duh

Comment: Wictor explains the encoding here: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-Claims-encoding-works-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Your screen shot has an accent over the g. Not sure how, but usually that is an encoding (Unicode) mismatch.

Comment: yeah, I thought it was strange too but it is expected. confirmed with the wictor post

Comment: I get 'Access Denied: Authentication is required' messages in the ULS logs. So I'm going to chalk this up to DNS issues accessing the ADFS server.

Comment: the endpoints that the custom claims provider did not match up perfectly, so this is closed.